# Get CheckBox.Checked in ASPxGridView Not Woking Properly

Tags: asp.net, aspxgridview

I have checkbox in ASPxGridView like this :

```
<dxwgv:ASPxGridView ID="Grid_Loading_Plan_Detail" runat="server" >          
...
<dxwgv:GridViewDataColumn Caption="#" VisibleIndex="1">
<DataItemTemplate>
<dxe:ASPxCheckBox ID="loadingStatus" runat="server" Checked='<%# GetChecked(Eval("loadingStatus").ToString()) %>'></dxe:ASPxCheckBox>
</DataItemTemplate>
</dxwgv:GridViewDataColumn>
...
</dxwgv:ASPxGridView>
```

It bind nicely when the checkbox loaded, here the function :

```
Public Function GetChecked(value As String) As Boolean
    Select Case value
        Case "1"
            Return True
        Case "0"
            Return False
        Case Else
            Return False
    End Select
End Function
```

The problem is, when check the `checked` status, it always return the loaded value. If the status is `checked` when loaded first time and then I do `unchecked` the CheckBox, it still return `checked`. Here How I get the value and save it to database :

```
Protected Sub btSimpan_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btSimpan.Click
    Try
        sqlstring = ""
        For i As Integer = 0 To Grid_Loading_Plan_Detail.VisibleRowCount - 1
            Dim loadingStatus As DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxCheckBox = Grid_Loading_Plan_Detail.FindRowCellTemplateControl(i, Grid_Loading_Plan_Detail.Columns(1), "loadingStatus")

            sqlstring = sqlstring & " UPDATE containerTransaction SET loadingStatus = '" & IIf(loadingStatus.Checked, "1", "0") & "' " & _
                        " WHERE ID = '" & Grid_Loading_Plan_Detail.GetRowValues(i, "ID") & "'; "
        Next

        If SQLExecuteNonQuery(sqlstring) > 0 Then
            Response.Redirect("loading-plan.aspx")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("Error btSimpan_Click <BR> " & ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

**ADDED**

Here how I bind the data :

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            Call Load_menu()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("Page_Load Exception :<br>" & ex.ToString)
    End Try

    If Not Session("Grid_Loading_Plan_Detail") Is Nothing Then
        Grid_Loading_Plan_Detail.DataSource = CType(Session("Grid_Loading_Plan_Detail"), DataTable)
        Grid_Loading_Plan_Detail.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

And here the `Load_menu()` function :

```
Private Sub Load_menu()
    Try
        sqlstring = "SELECT ID, code, date, container, seal, sender, receiver, [weight], loadingStatus " & _
            "FROM containerTransaction " & _
            "WHERE loadingCode = (SELECT TOP 1 code FROM loadingPlan WHERE ID = '" & ID & "') AND [status] = 1 " & _
            "ORDER BY [weight] "
        DS = SQLExecuteQuery(sqlstring)
        DT = DS.Tables(0)
        Session("Grid_Loading_Plan_Detail") = DT
        Grid_Loading_Plan_Detail.DataSource = DT
        Grid_Loading_Plan_Detail.KeyFieldName = "ID"
        Grid_Loading_Plan_Detail.DataBind()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("Load_Menu Exception :<br>" & ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

What have I missed here?

Comment: How and when are you binding data to the GridView? If you did not wrap the databinding inside an `IsPostBack` check, the state of the checkboxes will be overwritten by their database values every time a PostBack occurs.

Comment: You are also calling your checked function with the loadingStatus as the parameter so whenever it gets checked or unchecked it calls the loading function with the loading param

Comment: Not really sure that I fully understand the case but I think it might be an issue of `LoadPostData()` missing in your code. Try to call `DirectCast(btSimpan, IPostBackDataHandler).LoadPostData(btSimpan.UniqueID, Request.Form)` right after this line `Dim loadingStatus As DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxCheckBox =....` and see. btw I'm not really into VB.NET so I converted my C# snippet to this piece. The original in C# is `((IPostBackDataHandler)btSimpan).LoadPostData(btSimpan.UniqueID, Request.Form);`. Hope it helps.. If so please tell me and I will post a full answer tomorrow. Good luck :)

Comment: @VDWWD : I added the function in question, Thank you.

Comment: @MaCron : Do you have any other solution to bind it from database? Thank you

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar : Thank you for your help but I have try your code and still have same behaviour :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was session binding problem, it checked if session available, then data source will bind with that. The code is :

```
If Not Session("Grid_Loading_Plan_Detail") Is Nothing Then
    Grid_Loading_Plan_Detail.DataSource = CType(Session("Grid_Loading_Plan_Detail"), DataTable)
    Grid_Loading_Plan_Detail.DataBind()
End If
```

I removed that variable, and everything was ok.

### Edit

It have problem for searching and sorting if I removed the session checker. I have new solution from searching through some articles which fit better and searching/sorting feature in ASPxGridView still working.

Calling `load_menu()` function in init is the best way for this case :

```
Private Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    Call Load_menu()
End Sub
```

You can remove the session variable for this case. If there is problem with this solution, let me know.